# React firebase getting data from react route v params

Tags: reactjs, firebase

How to get data from firebase. im using react router v4. In the details page . "this.props.match.params.movie" this is diplaying only the movie name. I wanna show other details also from the databse. need help

```
componentDidMount() { 
    this.firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref("movies");
    this.firebaseRef.on('value', function (snapshot) {
        var movies = [];
        snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
            var movie = data.val();
            movie['.id'] = data.id;
            movies.push(movie);
        });
        this.setState({ movies });
    }.bind(this));
}
```

Index.js page

```
<Switch>
   <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
    <Route path="/create-movie" component={CreateMovie}/>
    <Route path="/details/:movie" component={Details} />
  </Switch>
```

Movie list page

```
<div className="col-md-3">
  <Link to={"/details/" + movie.name}>
    <img src={movie.image} alt={movie.name} className="thumbnail"/>
  </Link>
</div>
```

Comment: Try printing the details of match by `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.match)` .

Comment: No im not getting.. the result..My firebase database has some data in it..

Comment: Can you paste some of the firebase code you are doing to retrieve the movie? If you do `database.ref('movie')`, you should get the entire JSON along with it.

Comment: componentDidMount(){
      this.firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref("movies");
      this.firebaseRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
          var movies = [];
          snapshot.forEach(function(data){
            //console.log(data.val());
                var movie = data.val();
                movie['.id'] = data.id;
                movies.push(movie);
          })
          this.setState({movies})
      }.bind(this))
  }

Comment: the code looks alright. If the details of the movie are available within the movies, you should have the data atleast. A minor point: `movie.id = data.id` should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In details page, query Firebase again:

```
componentDidMount() { 
  this.firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref("movies");
  this.firebaseRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((data) => {
      var movie = data.val();
      if (movie.name === this.props.match.params.movie) {
        this.setState({ movie });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Use the arrow function to preserve context. Updated answer.

Comment: awesome it works !!!! Now how to display all data related to that movie  in the details page . should i add to movies array and loop through it ?

Comment: The movie detail is there in movie state. I am checking for name match while looping.

Comment: Thanx bro . I got it

Comment: Great, please mark the question as answered if it answered. Or upvote the answer if it helped.